# piecewise numpy function with integer arguments

Tags: function, integer, arguments, piecewise

I define the piecewise function

```
def Li(x):        
    return piecewise(x, [x < 0, x >= 0], [lambda t: sin(t), lambda t: cos(t)])
```

And when I evaluate `Li(1.0)`

The answer is correct

`Li(1.0)=array(0.5403023058681398)`,

But if I write `Li(1)` the answer is `array(0)`.

I don't understand this behaviour.

Comment: I get `ValueError: too many boolean indices` when running either example. You need to pass an `ndarray` to `Li()`. Please update your question with working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function runs correctly.

```
def Li(x):        
  return  piecewise(float(x), 
                    [x < 0, x >= 0], 
                    [lambda t: sin(t), lambda t: cos(t)])
```

Comment: if x is supposed to be np.array, it should be `x.astype(float)` instead of `float(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `piecewise()` converts the return values to the same type as the input so, when an integer is input an integer conversion is performed on the result, which is then returned. Because sine and cosine always return values between −1 and 1 all integer conversions will result in 0, 1 or -1 only - with the vast majority being 0.

```
>>> x=np.array([0.9])
>>> np.piecewise(x, [True], [float(x)])
array([ 0.9])
>>> x=np.array([1.0])
>>> np.piecewise(x, [True], [float(x)])
array([ 1.])
>>> x=np.array([1])
>>> np.piecewise(x, [True], [float(x)])
array([1])
>>> x=np.array([-1])
>>> np.piecewise(x, [True], [float(x)])
array([-1])
```

In the above I have explicitly cast the result to float, however, an integer input results in an integer output regardless of the explicit cast. I'd say that this is unexpected and I don't know why `piecewise()` should do this.

I don't know if you have something more elaborate in mind, however, you don't need `piecewise()` for this simple case; an if/else will suffice instead:

```
from math import sin, cos

def Li(t):        
    return sin(t) if t < 0 else cos(t)

>>> Li(0)
1.0
>>> Li(1)
0.5403023058681398
>>> Li(1.0)
0.5403023058681398
>>> Li(-1.0)
-0.8414709848078965
>>> Li(-1)
-0.8414709848078965
```

You can wrap the return value in an `numpy.array` if required.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but this example is taken and modified from

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html

But, in fact, using ipython with numpy 1.9

"""
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 18:22:21) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 2.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
"""

I have no errors, but "ValueError: too many boolean indices" error appears if I use python 2.7.3 with numpy 1.6

"""
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
"""
I test this function under Linux and Windows and the same error occurs.

Obviously, It is very easy to overcome this situation, but I think that 
this behaviour is a mistake in the numpy library.