# optimal way of defining a numerically stable sigmoid function for a list in python

Tags: python, sigmoid

For a scalar variable `x`, we know how to write down a numerically stable sigmoid function in python:

```py
def sigmoid(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return 1. / ( 1. + np.exp(-x) )
    else:
        return exp(x) / ( 1. + np.exp(x) )
```

For a list of scalars, say `z = [x_1, x_2, x_3, ...]`, and suppose we don't know the sign of each `x_i` beforehand, we could generalize the above definition and try:

```py
def sigmoid(z):
    result = []
    for x in z:
        if x >= 0:
            result.append(1. / ( 1. + np.exp(-x) ) )
        else:
            result.append( exp(x) / ( 1. + np.exp(x) ) )
    return result
```

This seems to work. However, I feel this is perhaps not the most pythonic way. How should I improve the definition in terms of 'cleanness'? Say, is there a way to use comprehension to shorten the function definition?

I'm sorry if this has been asked, because I cannot find similar questions on SO. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: It used to be as simple as `scipy.special.expit(x)`, but [someone changed it](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/30e181c1179177bd4e40c240ca70ce3b82dac873) back in 2016.

Comment: I'm not sure how important it is, though - I can find a few cases where the supposedly more stable version is about 1 ULP more accurate, but I can't find a solid analysis proving it's better, and [the closest thing to a source](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2013/numerical-optimizers-for-logistic-regression/) I've found analyzes the behavior of overflow wrong, coming to the incorrect conclusion that the straightforward 1/(1+exp(-x)) implementation will return infinity for x=-100.

Comment: It seems like the superiority of the "stable" version may be a myth, or at most a tiny precision advantage.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Infinity will be returned for ~`-710` with naive implementation (`numpy`, `double` precision)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fully correct answer (no warnings) was provided by [@hao peng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57178527/10886420) but solution wasn't explained clearly. This would be too long for a comment, so I'll go for an answer.

Let's start with analysis of a few answers (pure `numpy` answers only):

### [@DYZ accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976485/10886420)

This one is correct mathematically but still gives us a warning. Let's look at the code:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return np.where(
            x >= 0, # condition
            1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), # For positive values
            np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x)) # For negative values
    )
```

As both branches are evaluated (they are arguments, they have to be), the first branch will give us a warning for negative values and the second for positive.

Although the warnings will be raised, results from overflows **will not be incorporated**, hence the result is correct.

#### Downsides

- unnecessary evaluation of both branches (twice as many operations as needed)
- warnings are thrown

### [@ynn answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62860170/10886420)

This one is almost correct, **BUT** will work only on floating point values, see below:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return np.piecewise(
        x,
        [x > 0],
        [lambda i: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-i)), lambda i: np.exp(i) / (1 + np.exp(i))],
    )


sigmoid(np.array([0.0, 1.0]))  # [0.5 0.73105858] correct
sigmoid(np.array([0, 1]))  # [0, 0] incorrect
```

Why? Longer answer was provided by 
[@mhawke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060141/10886420) in another thread, but the main point is:

> It seems that piecewise() converts the return values to the same type
> as the input so, when an integer is input an integer conversion is
> performed on the result, which is then returned.

#### Downsides

- no automatic casting due to strange behavior of piecewise function

### Improved [@hao peng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57178527/10886420) answer

Idea of stable sigmoid comes from the fact that:

[image: sigmoid]

Both versions are equally efficient in terms of operations if coded correctly (one `exp` evaluation is enough). Now:

- `e^x` will overflow when `x` is positive
- `e^-x` will overflow when `x` is negative

Hence we have to branch on `x` equal to zero. Using `numpy`'s masking we can transform only the part of array which is positive or negative with specific sigmoid implementations.

See code comments for additional points:

```
def _positive_sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


def _negative_sigmoid(x):
    # Cache exp so you won't have to calculate it twice
    exp = np.exp(x)
    return exp / (exp + 1)


def sigmoid(x):
    positive = x >= 0
    # Boolean array inversion is faster than another comparison
    negative = ~positive

    # empty contains junk hence will be faster to allocate
    # Zeros has to zero-out the array after allocation, no need for that
    # See comment to the answer when it comes to dtype
    result = np.empty_like(x, dtype=np.float)
    result[positive] = _positive_sigmoid(x[positive])
    result[negative] = _negative_sigmoid(x[negative])

    return result
```

### Time measurements

Results (50 times case test from `ynn`):

```
289.5070939064026 #DYZ
222.49267292022705 #ynn
230.81086134910583 #this
```

Indeed piecewise seems faster (not sure about the reasons, maybe masking and additional masking ops make it slower).

Code below was used:

```
import time

import numpy as np


def _positive_sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


def _negative_sigmoid(x):
    # Cache exp so you won't have to calculate it twice
    exp = np.exp(x)
    return exp / (exp + 1)


def sigmoid(x):
    positive = x >= 0
    # Boolean array inversion is faster than another comparison
    negative = ~positive

    # empty contains juke hence will be faster to allocate than zeros
    result = np.empty_like(x)
    result[positive] = _positive_sigmoid(x[positive])
    result[negative] = _negative_sigmoid(x[negative])

    return result


N = int(1e4)
x = np.random.uniform(size=(N, N))

start: float = time.time()
for _ in range(50):
    y1 = np.where(x > 0, 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x)))
    y1 += 1
end: float = time.time()
print(end - start)

start: float = time.time()
for _ in range(50):
    y2 = np.piecewise(
        x,
        [x > 0],
        [lambda i: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-i)), lambda i: np.exp(i) / (1 + np.exp(i))],
    )
    y2 += 1
end: float = time.time()
print(end - start)

start: float = time.time()
for _ in range(50):
    y2 = sigmoid(x)
    y2 += 1
end: float = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Improved hao peng answer doesn’t seem to work if arrays contain integers instead of float

Comment: `result = np.empty_like(x, dtype=float)` should fix it

Comment: Is "caching" really necessary in hao peng's answer? Won't most interpreters already do this kind of optimization?

Comment: This is a nice and detailed summary of pros and cons of the solutions. I tagged this as the answer because it gives the most comprehensive scenario. Kudos to all who contributed to answering the question. You guys make Stackoverflow a fantastic place for learning.

Answer (score 11):

You are right, you can do better by using `np.where`, the numpy equivalent of `if`:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return np.where(x >= 0, 
                    1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), 
                    np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x)))
```

This function takes a numpy array `x` and returns a numpy array, too:

```
data = np.arange(-5,5)
sigmoid(data)
#array([0.00669285, 0.01798621, 0.04742587, 0.11920292, 0.26894142,
#       0.5       , 0.73105858, 0.88079708, 0.95257413, 0.98201379])
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. This is a lovely solution. May I ask is it possible to get rid of the element-wise for loop where we need to check the sign of x one at a time?

Comment: I do not follow you. There is no elementwise loop in the proposed solution.

Comment: Okay, I made a mistake when I passed a python list z to your definition, so an exception was raised. So I though I still need the for loop in the original definition. Passing np.array(z) works. I'll mark the question as solved. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you want to pass a list, just convert it to an array before passing (with `np.array(mylist)`).

Comment: seems like the `np.where` evaluates both branches and then chooses which one it needs, this results in misleading overflow warnings. something like `sigmoid(np.array(-300, np.float32))`

Comment: @titus You are right. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62860170/8776746) for a faster and more natural solution.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64717799/10886420) for discussion and downsides of this solution (unnecessary double evaluation which gives the runtime error)

Answer (score 5):

```
def sigmoid(x):
    """
    A numerically stable version of the logistic sigmoid function.
    """
    pos_mask = (x >= 0)
    neg_mask = (x < 0)
    z = np.zeros_like(x)
    z[pos_mask] = np.exp(-x[pos_mask])
    z[neg_mask] = np.exp(x[neg_mask])
    top = np.ones_like(x)
    top[neg_mask] = z[neg_mask]
    return top / (1 + z)
```

This piece of code comes from assignment3 of cs231n, I don't really understand why we should calculate it in this way, but I know this may be the code that you are looking for. Hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976485/8776746) is correct but, as pointed out by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976461/optimal-way-of-defining-a-numerically-stable-sigmoid-function-for-a-list-in-pyth#comment109724546_51976485), it calculates both branches and is thus problematic.

Rather, you may want to use [`np.piecewise()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html#numpy.piecewise). This is much faster, meaningful (`np.where` is **not** intended to define a piecewise function) and free of misleading warnings caused by entering into both branches.

### Benchmark

**Source Code**

```py
import numpy as np
import time

N: int = int(1e+4)

np.random.seed(0)

x: np.ndarray = np.random.random((N, N))
x *= 1e+3

start: float = time.time()
y1 = np.where(x > 0, 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x)))
end: float = time.time()
print()
print(end - start)

start: float = time.time()
y2 = np.piecewise(x, [x > 0], [lambda i: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-i)), lambda i: np.exp(i) / (1 + np.exp(i))])
end: float = time.time()
print(end - start)

assert (np.array_equal(y1, y2))
```

**Result**

`np.piecewise()` is silent and twice faster!

```
test.py:12: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  y1 = np.where(x > 0, 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x)))
test.py:12: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  y1 = np.where(x > 0, 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x)))

6.32736349105835
3.138420343399048
```

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64717799/10886420) for comparison and why your solution does not work for edge case (`np.array` is integer).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to your code is the following:

```
def sigmoid(z):
    return [(1. / (1. + np.exp(-x)) if x >= 0 else (np.exp(x) / (1. + np.exp(x))) for x in z]
```

Comment: There is really no point in using numpy functions and not using numpy vectorization.

Comment: This is a very nice and clean alternative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DYZ While I agree that your solution is shorter and more consequent, it is preferred to use list comprehensions instead of for loops. I will edit my answer so that everyone can see that this is an alternative to the code posted in the question, not to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one trick, I guess np.where or torch.where are implemented in the same manner to deal with binary conditions:

```
def sigmoid(x, max_v=1.0):    
    sign = (torch.sign(x) + 3)//3
    x = torch.abs(x)
    res = max_v/(1 + torch.exp(-x))
    res = res * sign + (1 - sign) * (max_v - res)
    return res
```